# Eclipse Juno Service Release 1 has No Watch window

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-juno

As this [page](http://agile.csc.ncsu.edu/SEMaterials/tutorials/eclipse-debugger/) suggest me I can highlight the expression (just like visual studio IDE) and add it into the watch window,
[image]

but I cannot find any "watch" option as the following capture screen, please advice me what steps I have missed, thanks!

[image]

Comment: make sure to select the correct instance in the debug view. there is a terminated `_proxy.jsp` instance, maybe thats still selected. expand tomcat stack and select the active entry, it should work then

Comment: Thanks for your response! However I have selected the <teminated> _proxy.jsp [Run on Server] and there is nothing changed.